# Python| if-elif-else

Tags: python

Пишет ошибка в 6 строке-  invalid syntax
Так в чем ошибка?

```
alien_color = ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
if 'green' in alien_color:
    print("Congratulations, you have earned 5 points!")
elif 'yellow' in alien_color:
    print("Congratulations, you have earned 10 points!")
else 'red' in alien_color:
    print("Congratulations, you have earned 15 points!")
```

Comment: У else не может быть условия. Поменяйте его на elif.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что после `else` всегда должен быть таким:

```
else:
   ...
```

Место `else` вам надо написать `elif`

```
alien_color = ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
if 'green' in alien_color:
    print("Congratulations, you have earned 5 points!")
elif 'yellow' in alien_color:
    print("Congratulations, you have earned 10 points!")
elif 'red' in alien_color:
    print("Congratulations, you have earned 15 points!")
```

Comment: А команда Else сейчас не воспринемается Python? У меня и в других кодах else не принимает...

Comment: @SvyatoslavPudovkin воспринимается. Просто в `else` нельзя ничего писать, он предназначен не для этого

Answer (score 1):

Нужно заменить else на elif

```
alien_color = ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
if 'green' in alien_color:
    print("Congratulations, you have earned 5 points!")
elif 'yellow' in alien_color:
    print("Congratulations, you have earned 10 points!")
elif 'red' in alien_color:
    print("Congratulations, you have earned 15 points!")
```

else, это то, что выполнит программа если не один из if не прошёл проверку, он не принимает что-то после себя кроме двоеточия:

```
if 1 == 0:
    print(1)
else:
    print(2)
```

В данном случае будет выведено 2, так как первая проверка не выполнилась

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вместо else написать elif. У тебя должно происходить условие 'red', а если нет других вариантов, то можно убрать `'red' in alien_color`и оставить
`alien_color = ['green', 'yellow', 'red']`

```
if 'green' in alien_color:
    print("Congratulations, you have earned 5 points!")
elif 'yellow' in alien_color:
    print("Congratulations, you have earned 10 points!")
else :
    print("Congratulations, you have earned 15 points!")`
```